# Parent-Child object relationship disappears after exporting Wavefront(obj) format

Tags: export, parent

I have 2 objects in Blender named A and B.

I set A as a parent of B by ctrl+p command after choosing both objects.

After I exported it as a wavefront (.obj) format , when I try to import it in a new Blender, the parent-child relationship disappears and 2 objects seems independent of each other. Is there an export option that I missed in order to preserve child-parent relationship ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Wikipedia page for [Wavefront obj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Other_geometry_formats) :

> "Obj files also do not support mesh hierarchies"

If you want to keep the hierarchy, you'll have to use another format such as fbx.